# Converting trilateration results to pixel values for displaying on a live map in a Django app

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a django app that uses wifi trilateration to calculate a device's location in `x,y`.  The calculated `x,y` values are expressed according to the real world locations of 3 wifi access points `x1,y1`, `x2,y2`, `x3,y3`. In the calculations `x1, y1` is treated as the point of origin. After the trilateration is done, I want to show the location on a live map using ajax to send the device's live location.
the map in my app is contained within a div with class .level.level--current which only covers part of the screen.[image: map]
how can i go from the `x,y` value given by the trilateration to pixel values that can be expressed within the map?
The trilateration point of origin, `x1,y1`, may be different from the first pixel of the .level.level--current div.